# Removing epsilon-production from grammar

Tags: compiler-construction, context-free-grammar, formal-languages

I am wondering how to eliminate epsilon-productions in grammar:

```
 S → S0 
 S → 1
 S → AB
 B → AC
 A → ε
 C → ε
```

I know that because of `C → ε` and `A → ε` we have to rewrite:
`B → AC` as:

```
 B → A | C | AC
```

and `S → AB` as

```
S → A | B | AB
```

But production `A → ε` and `C → ε` seems to eliminate states A,B and C, leaving only productions:

```
 S → S0 | 0
 S → 1
```

Am I correct?

Answer (score 0):

Yes. You are correct.

This what I got:

```
S → S0 
S → 1
S → AB
B → AC
A → ε
C → ε
```

After removing A,B,C because they all go to epi.

```
S → S0 
S → 1
S → ε
```

Removing S → ε means rewriting so S → S0 to include all possible outcomes which is S0 | 0. Leaving:

```
S → S0 | 0
S → 1
```